# Slow Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to make this run a bit faster?

```
return mb_entities.prospects.
         FirstOrDefault(x => x.address == person.Add &&
                x.homePhone == person.HPhone &&
                x.bizPhone == person.BPhone && 
                x.cellPhone == person.CPhone &&
                x.city == person.City &&
                x.state == person.State && 
                x.zip == person.Zip &&
                x.email == person.Email &&
                x.firstName == person.FName &&
                x.lastName == person.LName &&
                x.middleName == person.MName &&
                x.genCode == person.GC) ?? new prospect();
```

Right now it runs in between 160 and 180 Milliseconds. This would be ok if I didn't have to do it 1000 times.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 160 ms is really long. It seems that you are processing to filter your results on the client side. I would make a db-query that returns only the rows that match your criteria.

Comment: Another minor tip: re-arrange your criteria so it is in the order of most selective to least selective -- that way the short-circuiting of the `&&` operator will occur quicker.

Comment: Just out of curiousity why are you doing that, as oposed to finding it by a key of some sort?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm allowing users to call into an API to import records, so I want to make sure I'm not getting a bunch of duplicated data. So I run this query to see if there are any matches in the database already.

Comment: Makes sense, have you thought about some sort of hash/checksum, you could index the tables on then, and limit the amount of candidates to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an index on the most selective columns (for example, on email, zip and lastname). This will speed it up. It should be one index on multiple columns.

You must have a lot of records in your table that it takes 160ms to execute this once. This is unusually long, even when no index is present.

Comment: It's a pretty large table, yeah. Several hundred thousand records... Thanks for the tip, I'm gonna go try it out now!

Comment: I figure that in most cases, unless doing so would devastate performance, any column that would appear in a where clause and *can* be indexed, *should* be indexed. The performance gains on selects, which consistitute the vast majority of database operations, is astounding.

Comment: I recommended indexing only a subset for space reasons. It won't make much of a difference if his index returns exactly one row or if it returns 5 superfluous rows. I wouldn't recommend him to duplicate the entire table in an NC index because it is big.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server as your database? If so, you should run SQL Server profiler while you are running your workload. Then use captured trace as input to the index tuning wizard.  The index tuning wizard will analyze the workload and the distribution of the data and provide index recommendations.